# Conexão JDBC Java Web e SQL Server 2014

Tags: java, sql-server, aplicação-web

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de um portal utilizando JAVA Web e base de dados em SQL Server 2014.

Nunca trabalhei com SQL Server e há um problema que não estou conseguindo encontrar a solução.

Eis o problema:  A conexão acontece normalmente através desta classe:

```
public class ConexaoFactory {
private static String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=XXXXXX;databa‌​seName=XXXXXX";

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL);

    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

}
```

Porém ao tentar fazer uma requisição no banco de dados, tenho um erro:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Nome de objeto 'AGENDA' inválido.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:885)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:778)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:677)
at br.com.portalpedsys.dao.UsuarioDAO.listar(UsuarioDAO.java:22)
at br.com.portalpedsys.test.TesteConexao.main(TesteConexao.java:16)
```

A requisição esta sendo feito da classe DAO à seguir:

```
public class UsuarioDAO {
    public ArrayList<Usuario> listar() throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT * FROM AGENDA");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<Usuario> fabArray = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        while (resultado.next()) {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setCgccpf(resultado.getString("cgccpf"));
            usuario.setNomrep(resultado.getString("nomrep"));
            fabArray.add(usuario);
        }
        return fabArray;
    }
}
```

O banco de dados está local, em meu computador.

O que há de errado aqui?
Por que não reconhece as tabelas do banco de dados?

Por favor, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar um `USE [DatabaseName]` antes do seu select, esse erro geralmente é 
pode ser ocasionado por dois motivos :

- Falta de permissões do usuário usado para acessar a conta;
- O jdbc não sabe para qual banco de dados apontar (acho que é seu caso);

Comment: Olá Lucas, deu certo com sua dica.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda.